# Absolutely Position Element Around a Circle

Tags: javascript, css, geometry, trigonometry

I've got some html with an embedded SVG within it as below

```
<section id="deck-head">

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="250" height="250">

        <g>
            <title>Marker</title>
            <g id="marker-frame">
                <path fill="white" d="m133.300003,64.800003l0,-33.500004l-16.100006,0l0,33.299999c-30.799995,3.700005 -53.499996,29.599998 -53.499996,60.800003c0,33.900002 27.600002,61.299995 61.299999,61.299995s61.300003,-27.399994 61.300003,-61.299995c0,-30.900002 -23.600006,-56.599998 -53,-60.599998zm-53.5,60.699997c0,-24.900002 20.299995,-45.199997 45.199997,-45.199997s45.199997,20.299995 45.199997,45.199997s-20.199997,45.300003 -45.199997,45.300003s-45.199997,-20.400009 -45.199997,-45.300003z"/>
            </g>
        </g>

    </svg>

    <mark>90&deg;</mark>

</section>
```

I need to be able to replicate the following layout without using any external javascript libraries

[image: Desired Layout]

*Ignore Red*

I've managed to rotate the SVG simply enough to face the correct direction - however the trouble I'm having is getting the  element to absolutely position by the tick/tip of the pink circle, depending on where its rotated to.

The logic in my head that I was following was something along the lines of:
Get the circle center point
Get the rotation
Find out what the left & top position would be based off the above.

However I'm completely lost on what the calculation would be to get the top and left coordinates to be able to absolutely position the mark where it should be.

Comment: "however the trouble I'm having is getting the mark to display by the tip" - What does that mean?

Comment: Why has this been down voted exactly?

Comment: the question wasn't exactly clear

Comment: @Brennan is that any clearer?

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599782/positioning-divs-in-a-circle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are just simple polar coordinates. jQuery is not needed, just for easier manipulations.

```js
var angle = 0, center = 125, radius = 110, pi = Math.PI;
setInterval(function(){
 angle += 1;
 $('#c').attr('transform', 'rotate(' + angle + ', 125, 125)');
 // calculate new coordinates for mark
 var x = center + radius * Math.cos(angle * pi / 180 - pi / 2);
 var y = center + radius * Math.sin(angle * pi / 180 - pi / 2);
 $('#m').css({top: y + 'px', left: x + 'px'});
}, 100);
```

```css
body {background-color:black;}
#m {position:absolute;}
section {poisition:relative;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="deck-head">

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="250" height="250">

        <g>
            <title>Marker</title>
            <g id="marker-frame">
                <path fill="white" id="c" d="m133.300003,64.800003l0,-33.500004l-16.100006,0l0,33.299999c-30.799995,3.700005 -53.499996,29.599998 -53.499996,60.800003c0,33.900002 27.600002,61.299995 61.299999,61.299995s61.300003,-27.399994 61.300003,-61.299995c0,-30.900002 -23.600006,-56.599998 -53,-60.599998zm-53.5,60.699997c0,-24.900002 20.299995,-45.199997 45.199997,-45.199997s45.199997,20.299995 45.199997,45.199997s-20.199997,45.300003 -45.199997,45.300003s-45.199997,-20.400009 -45.199997,-45.300003z"/>
            </g>
        </g>

    </svg>

    <mark id='m'>90&deg;</mark>

</section>
```